# Overlapping Points in Polar Coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a polar chart in R. However, my first and last point end up being plotted at the same point. I would prefer not to create another row in my dataframe such that it would still have the overlap, but the new row would be a dummy row. I would like there to simply be `k` points of equi distance from each other. So `1` is plotted at `r=5` and `theta=pi/2`. The next point `2` at `r=5` and `theta=9pi/10`, etc Observe,

```
k<-5   
x_vector<-seq(1,k,1)
radius<-rep(5,k,1)
name<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
df<-data.frame(x_vector,radius,name)
p<-ggplot()+
 geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x_vector,y=radius,color=name,fill=name),size=3,shape=21)+
coord_polar(theta='x',start=0,direction=-1,clip='on')+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,5))
p
```

Creates this:
[image]

As you can see, I would like the `1` and `5` points to be seperate. Also I do not want to plot them in cartesian and then convert. I feel like this is an issue others have encountered, but cannot find something on it.

Comment: So what is your desired result? How do you want them drawn such that they don't overlap? Where do you want them to wind up? Do you want some sort of gap in the plot?

Comment: Would `p + expand_limits(x = 0)` achieve the look you want?

Comment: Okay. `expand_limits(x=0)` worked. Now just have to figure out how?